# Why does the real component of inner product being zero imply that the inner product is 0 in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I’m reading a [proof](http://www-math.mit.edu/~dav/spectral.pdf) of spectral theorem and in there they say if $Re \langle{ v,u \rangle} = 0$ then $\langle{ v,u \rangle} = 0$.

I don’t know why this wasn’t proven but I’d like to know why this is true.[image][image]

Comment: I was thinking it would follow from $$Re \langle{ S(v_0),u \rangle}=0 \Rightarrow \overline{\langle{ S(v_0),u \rangle}} = \langle{ u,S(v_0) \rangle} = -\langle{S(v_0), u\rangle}$$ but this doesn't show the complex component is 0 unless $\langle{u,v\rangle}=\langle{v,u\rangle}$.

This is why I say people need to detail this stuff in their work.

Comment: In general, it doesn't imply it. The dot product can be purely imaginary and non-zero, e.g. $(1,i)\cdot(0,1)=i$. It is unclear what $S$ is, but the author apparently uses some additional information about it.

Comment: Added a link with more detail. Still don't see why his assertion is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the hermitian inner product can be nonzero even though its real part is zero. But this argument is not about a single pair of vectors. We are told that *whenever* $\langle v_0,u\rangle = 0$, then $\text{Re}\langle S(v_0),u\rangle = 0$.
So, if we know this is true for some vector $u$, then it holds for all $e^{i\theta}u$ as well (because $\langle v_0,e^{i\theta}u\rangle = e^{-i\theta}\langle v_0,u\rangle = e^{-i\theta}0 = 0$).

Thus, note that if $\langle S(v_0),u\rangle = ci$ is pure imaginary ($c$ real, of course), it will follow that $\langle S(v_0),iu\rangle = -i(ci) = c$ is real. But we already said that the real part of this inner product must be $0$; hence $c=0$ and $\langle S(v_0),u\rangle = 0$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you! Also really liked your textbook by the way. Used it for some of my students and they agreed.

Comment: And also this looks like the type of argument that shouldn’t be left for the reader to deduce on his or her own...  It’s clever.

Comment: Which text? :) Thanks. ... Well, remember that those notes were written for MIT students, who are expected to be quick *and* clever.  I doubt that was written intended as a text for the general public. (By the way, if you're doing the proof with a *real* operator, as I usually have done in my various courses, then this subtlety doesn't show up.)

Comment: Multivariable Mathematics. Liked the integration of linear algebra and analysis a lot there--and I consult it from time to time when I forget little details when working on stats research.

Comment: Oh, cool. Thanks again. You (or your students) might find (some of?) my 112 lectures on that material posted on YouTube useful.